# How to detect silent 401 errors in GA Core Reporting API?

Tags: google-analytics, jwt, google-analytics-api

I am making several requests to Google Analytics' Core Reporting API v4, and I am trying to monitor the number of errors in order to respect the [API error limits](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/limits-quotas#reporting_apis_request_errors).

When I look at the "APIs and Services" Console, I have about 5% of 401 errors that are not caught (not even detected) by my code below.

What could explain these 401s and how could I prevent them (or at least monitor them) ?

The code : first I need to authenticate my server using a JWT Token.

```
const { google } = require('googleapis');

// JWT Authentication
const key = require('./credentials.json');

const jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT(
  key.client_email,
  null,
  key.private_key,
  ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics'], // an array of auth scopes
  null,
);

// Instantiate GA Core Reporting v4 client
const analyticsreporting = google.analyticsreporting({
  version: 'v4',
  auth: jwtClient,
  scopes: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics',
});
```

Then I make an authenticated request :

```
// Query the API and print the results to the page.
exports.gaRequestCore = function (segmentValue) {
  const promise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    jwtClient.authorize(function (authErr, tokens) {
      if (authErr) {
        return reject(authErr);
      }
      // Make an authorized request
      const callback = (err, response) => {
        if (err) {
         return reject(err);
        }
        if (response.status !== 200) {
          console.log(‘response status', response.status);
        }
        return resolve(response);
      }
      analyticsreporting.reports.batchGet(params(segmentValue), options, callback);
    })
  });
  return promise;
};
```

502 and 503 errors are rejected in the callback or console logged, but I do not have any 401s.